# Bitmap image issue android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

This is my code to draw rectangle over an image in specified position. rectangle is drawn but my problem is that  now my image is not shown.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
float left = 20;
float topy = 20;
float right = 50;
float bottom = 50;
canvas.drawRect(left, topy, right, bottom, paint);
```

Please tell anything wrong on my code ?

Comment: my mistake changed...

Comment: any idea whats wrong here ??

Comment: i think you need to draw 4 lines at four edges!

Comment: @user2291423, I found problem solution, check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `StrokeWidth` to `50`. which is very huge. Either remove it or decrease. Otherwise code is fine to draw rectangle.

I tried following code.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
button.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // canvas background fill 
canvas.drawPaint(paint); // just to check how big rectangle draw on canvas
    //you can remove 2 above lines. its my testing
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(5); //5 instead of 50
float left = 20;
float topy = 20;
float right = 50;
float bottom = 50;
canvas.drawRect(left, topy, right, bottom, paint);
```

**Edit**

You can try following layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearParentHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMainImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <com.customview.CustomRectangleOverlayView
            android:id="@+id/photoSortrView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgMainImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgMainImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgMainImage"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgMainImage" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In which, two views are in RelativeLayout. One is image view, Second is your Custom View which is used to draw rectangles. Your ImageView will be overlaped with second one. Second view has transparency. So, this will look like you are drawing rectangle on original image.

Comment: why don't you use another view to draw rectangle with transparency? or set your image in background instead of source of imageview.

Comment: @chinthan actually i want , like in Facebook tag some part of photos

Comment: okay. Got your problem. Wait. Solve your problem. Give 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Bitmap bm = new BitmapFactory().decodeResource(getResources(), your_image_id, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    float left = 20;
    float topy = 20;
    float right = 50;
    float bottom = 50;
    canvas.drawRect(left, topy, right, bottom, paint);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Hi tried this but on the first line when changing to my image is showing error..:(

Comment: I thought you need to draw a rectangle on a image, so you refer @Arun's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do image first mutable and then draw rectangle on it and gain make it immutable-

```
bitmap3=mutableimage3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,true);// mutable image.

bitmap3=mutableimage3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false);//immutable
```